# Update single cell in datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, database, wpf, grid, cell

I have a datagrid in my WPF application. In one column I have an int (column name = `Amount`).

So for example there will be a number "4" in the cell. I can edit "4" in the DataGrid to "3".

After editing, I will push the button "Update" so my database column `Amount` will be updated.

It is working, but it update all the cells in the column `Amount` to the Id number of the chosen row.

This is my code in the xaml.cs file:

```
 private void Update(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        DataRowView o = (DataRowView)g2.SelectedItem;
        int Amount = Convert.ToInt32(o.Row.ItemArray[0]);

        try
        {
            const string query = @"UPDATE [Stock] SET [STOCK].Amount = @Aantal;";
           
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"...."))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Amount;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Update complete");
            binddatagrid();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred:\r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your database query is updating the `Amount` column of every row in the `[Stock]` table. You need to add a `WHERE` clause to your database query so that you only update the `[Stock]` row in the database that corresponds to the selected row in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Ah! Oké so when I try this: 
@"UPDATE [Stock] SET [STOCK].Amount WHERE [STOCK].Id = @Aantal;"

I get an Error "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database query is updating the `Amount` column in every row in the `[Stock]` table. You need to add a `WHERE` clause to your database query so that you only update the `[Stock]` row in the database that corresponds to the selected row in the `DataGrid`.

I don't know what your database schema looks like, but I'm assuming that the `[Stock]` table has an `Id` column. If so, the query might look something like this:

`UPDATE [Stock] SET [Stock].Amount = @Anatal WHERE [Stock].Id = @Id`

Notice that the query now has a second parameter, `@Id`. That means that you'll need to get the `Id` from the selected row in much the same way that you're currently getting the `Amount`.

`int id = Convert.ToInt32(o.Row.ItemArray[1]);`

I used `o.Row.ItemArray[1]`, but I don't know what index the `Id` will actually be stored at. You'll have to use that index to get the correct `Id`.

Since your query has a second parameter, you also need to add it to the `Parameters` collection of the `SqlCommand` instance. Just like how you're doing with `Amount`.

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;`

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I've learned a lot thanks to you!